# Unable to access the members of a dictionary using the name of the attributes as key

Tags: python-3.x

I had a list of x coordinates(xlist) and another list of y coordinates(ylist). I zipped them together. Then, I had the attribute (or rather names) (cocoBind)for each of these coordinates. I zipped cocoBind and zipped xlist and ylist as:

```
    cocoDict = dict(zip(cocoBind,zip(xlist,ylist)))
```

to create a dictionary. This is how print(cocoDict) prints out:

```
    {<CocoPart.Nose: 0>: (252, 126), <CocoPart.Neck: 1>: (248, 179), 

    <CocoPart.RShoulder: 2>: (215, 175), <CocoPart.RElbow: 3>: (199, 220), 

    <CocoPart.LShoulder: 5>: (282, 171), <CocoPart.LElbow: 6>: (322, 224), 

    <CocoPart.LWrist: 7>: (282, 273), <CocoPart.RHip: 8>: (222, 314), 

    <CocoPart.RKnee: 9>: (275, 367), <CocoPart.LHip: 11>: (257, 310), 

    <CocoPart.LKnee: 12>: (282, 363), <CocoPart.REye: 14>: (243, 114), 

    <CocoPart.LEye: 15>: (262, 114), <CocoPart.REar: 16>: (231, 122), 

    <CocoPart.LEar: 17>: (275, 122)}
```

I need to calcuate the distance between any two of these coordinates. I have a fuction for that. No issue with that. But I need to access these coordinates using their names (**eg. Distance(cocoDict.Nose, cocoDict.Neck)**). Although this syntax is invalid.

What changes should I make to the command to get the coordinates through their  name. (P.S: I tried with tuples too, but it didn't work out)
The CocoPart class is defined as:

```
    class CocoPart(Enum):
Nose = 0
Neck = 1
RShoulder = 2
RElbow = 3
RWrist = 4
LShoulder = 5
LElbow = 6
LWrist = 7
RHip = 8
RKnee = 9
RAnkle = 10
LHip = 11
LKnee = 12
LAnkle = 13
REye = 14
LEye = 15
REar = 16
LEar = 17
Background = 18
```

whereas the cocoBind is printed below:

```
    [<CocoPart.Nose: 0>, <CocoPart.Neck: 1>, <CocoPart.RShoulder: 2>, <CocoPart.RElbow: 3>, <CocoPart.LShoulder: 5>, <CocoPart.LElbow: 6>, <CocoPart.LWrist: 7>, <CocoPart.RHip: 8>, <CocoPart.RKnee: 9>, <CocoPart.LHip: 11>, <CocoPart.LKnee: 12>, <CocoPart.REye: 14>, <CocoPart.LEye: 15>, <CocoPart.REar: 16>, <CocoPart.LEar: 17>]
```

The xlist, ylist and cocoBind was assigned as follows:

```
            #for loop
            xlist.append(center[0])
            ylist.append(center[1])              
            cocoBind.append(CocoPart(i))
```

Comment: can you add the definition of cocopart class, as well as the contents of cocoBind

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: also can u add how you assign cocobind, as well as how you assign  xlist and ylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got the answer.
The coordinate was printed this way :

```
    print(cocoDict[CocoPart.Neck])
```

The distance got printed this way:

```
    print(distance(cocoDict[CocoPart.Neck], cocoDict[CocoPart.LWrist]))
```

Comment: This is quite an abnormal situation I am dealing with. Both the above commands seem to work fine. But on trying any command to look for a key to be there or not, all I get is "KeyError"